# Replace only the second occurance of string in a line in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like `"ven|ven|vett|vejj|ven|ven"`. Treat each `"|"` delimiter for each column.

By splitting the string with `"|"` saving all the columns in array and reading each column into `$str`

So, I'm trying to do this as

```
$string =~ s/$str/venky/g if $str =~ /ven/i; # it will do globally.
```

Which not met the requirement.

On-demand basis, I need to replace string at the particular number of occurrence of the string.

For example, I've a request to change 2nd occurrence of `"ven"` to *venky*.

Then how can I met this requirement simply? Is it some-thing like

```
$string =~ s/ven/venky/2;
```

As of my knowledge we have 'o' for replace once and 'g' for globally. I'm struggling for the solution to get the replacement at particular occurrence. And I should not use `pos()` to get the position, because string keeps on change. It becomes difficult to trace it every-time. That's my intention.

Please help me on this regard.

Comment: Please to suggest that a post needs to be edited by swearing at poster. That helps nobody.

Answer (score 1):

There is no flag that you can add to the regex that will do this.

The easiest way would be to split and loop. However, if you insist to use one regex, it is doable:

```
/^(?:[^v]|v[^e]|ve[^n])*ven(?:[^v]|v[^e]|ve[^n])*\Kven/
```

If you want to replace the **N**th occurrence instead of the second, you can do:

```
/^(?:(?:[^v]|v[^e]|ve[^n])*ven){N-1}(?:[^v]|v[^e]|ve[^n])*\Kven/
```

The general idea:

`(?:[^v]|v[^e]|ve[^n])*` - matches any string that isn't part of `ven`

`\K` is a cool matcher that drops everything matched so far, so you can sort of use it as a lookbehind with variable length

Comment: The problem with this is that it's probably just example data. Though nice regex. :)

Comment: `ven` and **N** can be replaced with anything. If the alternative to `ven` is longer, a negative lookahead can be used instead. But I do agree that this isn't the way to do it, it was mainly for the lolz. :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're replacing every instance of'ven' with 'venky' if your string contains a match for `ven`, which of course it does.

What I assume you're trying to do is to substitute 'ven' for 'venky' within your string if it's the second element:

```
my $string = 'ven|ven|vett|vejj|ven|ven';

my @elements = split(/\|/, $string);

my $count;
foreach (@elements){
    $count++;
    s/$_/venky/g if /ven/i and $count == 2;
}

print join('|', @elements);
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach was already pretty good. What you described makes sense, but I think you are having trouble implementing it.

I created a function to do the work. It takes 4 arguments:

- `$string` is the string we want to work on
- `$n` is the *nth* occurance you want to replace
- `$needle` is the thing you want to replace – thing *needle in a haystack*

  Note that right now we allow to pass stuff that might contain regular expressions. So you would have to use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) on it or match with `/\Q$needle\E/`
- `$replacement` is the replacement for the `$needle`

The idea is to split up the string, then check each element if it matches the pattern (`$needle`) and keep track of how many have matched. If the nth one is reached, replace it and stop processing. Then put the string back together.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

say replace_nth_occurance("ven|ven|vett|vejj|ven|ven", 2, 'ven', 'venky');

sub replace_nth_occurance {
  my ($string, $n, $needle, $replacement) = @_;

  # take the string appart
  my @elements = split /\|/, $string;

  my $count = 0; # keep track of ...
  foreach my $e (@elements) {
    $count++ if $e =~ m/$needle/;    # ... how many matches we've found
    if ($count == $n) {
      $e =~ s/$needle/$replacement/; # replace
      last;                          # and stop processing
    }
  }

  # put it back into the pipe-separated format
  return join '|', @elements;
}
```

**Output**:

```
ven|venky|vett|vejj|ven|ven
```

Answer (score -1):

To replace the n'th occurrence of "ven" to "venky":

```
my $n = 3;
my $test = "seven given ravens";
$test =~ s/ven/--$n == 0 ? "venky" : $&/eg;
```

This uses the ability with the /e flag to specify the substitution part as an expression.